# Which data format convention in Keras (channels_last or channels_first) should be used when?

Tags: keras, channel, dataformat, image-formats

I'm a newbie in deep learning and confused which data format convention should be used when. According to the https://keras.io/backend/, there are two data format conventions.

**channels_last** for 2D data:   (rows, cols, **channels**)
**channels_first:** for 2D data: (**channels**, rows, cols)

Why there is a **channels_first** option in Keras? When should I use it? Is there any historical reason like BGR usage in OpenCV?

> *" BGR was a choice made for historical reasons and now we have to live with it. In other words, **BGR is the horse’s ass in OpenCV**."* 
>   https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason that there are two data formats, is that Keras supports Theano as another backend too. In Theano, the first axis represents the channels.

Comment: You are right! 
"*There are two conventions for shapes of images tensors: the channels-last convention (used by TensorFlow) and the channels-first convention (used by Theano).*"
**Deep Learning with Python - François Chollet**

Answer (score 2):

**Tensorflow**
data_format accepts 2 values- channels_last (default) or channels_first.

Its represents the ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.

**channels_last** corresponds to inputs with shape `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`

**channels_first** corresponds to inputs with shape `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`.

Code:  `tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), data_format='channels_last')`
*No batch size*

[Look at Tensorflow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D)